# TensorFlow: initializing state for RNN between inferences in Android

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, lstm

We have a working TensorFlow network (graphdef) running on Android and I'm noting that the inference results over time tend to be correlated.  That is if label A is returned there will tend to be a stream of A's that follow in time, even when the input data switches to data that should generate B labels.  Eventually, the results will switch to B but there seems to be a lag and suggests the RNN is stateful between inference calls.  Our network is using RNN/LSTMs.

```
cellLSTM    = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(nHidden)
cellsLSTM   = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cellLSTM] * 2)
RNNout, RNNstates = tf.nn.rnn(cellsLSTM, Xin)
```

I'm wondering if I need to reinitialize the RNN state between inference calls.  I will note that no such method is available in the TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java interface.   I imagine that it would be possible to insert an RNN cell initialization node into the graph that could be activated with a node value (using FillNodeInt or similar).

So my question is: what is best practise with RNN/LSTMs in Tensorflow. Does one need to clear state between inferences?  If so, how does one do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't comment on general practice for RNN state initialization, here is how we managed to force the initial state definition.  The problem was that while the batch size was indeed a constant parameter for the training set, it was not for the Test set.  The test set is always 20% of the data corpus and so its size is different with each change to the corpus.
The solution was to create a new variable for the batchsize:

```
batch_size_T  = tf.shape(Xin)[0]
```

where `Xin` is the input Tensor of size [b x m x n] where `b` is the batch size and `m x n` is the size of the training frame.  Xin is fed in from the `feed_dict`.

The initial state can then be defined as:

```
initial_state = lstm_cells.zero_state(batch_size_T, tf.float32)
```

Finally, the RNN is defined in terms of the new Dynamic RNN:

```
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm_cells, inputs=Xin, dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=initial_state)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does one need to clear state between inferences?

I think that depends on how the RNN was trained and how you are using it. But, I would guess that the network would work pretty well with and without resetting state.

> how does one do it?

Evaluate the initialization ops for each tensor associated with the initial state.

Comment: On the contrary, RNNs can carry state forward with them over time.  When not initialized and If trained with the random series of frames from the Training session, they tend to be less predictable in real data.  So making sure that it is starting each frame with zero state matters a lot.  I have seen some commentary on the TF Issue boards that the new `dynamic_rnn` implementation automatically initializes its state to zero with each frame.  However, in my case I had seen anomalies, and wanted to guarantee initialization as part of the graph.